# Is it possible to refresh a div on a radio button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

Is it possible to refresh a div on a radio button click presented within that div?

I have this scenario;

Using jQuery,I need to refresh a div on a radio button click.And the radio button is present in that particular div that I need to be refreshed.

All the research that I have done so far, webPages/forums I've seen, they all have examples of buttons outside the div that is supposed to be refreshed.

I have something like:

```
<div class="abc">

    <ul class="typeA">
        <li><input name="regType34" onclick="javascript:loadRegister('34',$(this).attr('data-title'));" value="REG" type="radio" id="34_1" class="MyStyle" data-title="reg"  checked="checked">
        <label for="34_1" style="background-position: 0px -67px;">Register</label></li>
        <li><input name="regType34" onclick="javascript:loadGraph('34',$(this).attr('data-title'));" value="GRA" type="radio" id="34_2" class="MyStyle" data-title="gra"> <label for="34_2">Graph</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is it possible that when user click on "regType34", complete div "abc" will get refreshed?

**Refresh means reloading of the content of div**

Comment: what do you mean by refreshed? do yo mean reload the contents of teh div from the server again... if so what should happen to the checked state... should it retain the radio checked by the user....

Comment: yes, I mean reload the content of the div on the basis of check.checked state should be retained as per what user checked.

Comment: yes. I think you can just bind a click event handler on the radio button and when its clicked refresh the div by sending an ajax request

Comment: Just do it like this. By using the onclick function in jquery, and give a condition for check whick radio button is selected. After that call a function, In which do whatever you needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this :
    $("input[name=regType34]").click(function(){
    $("#abc").html("html that you want to show on div refresh");
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below JQuery code which is to refresh div element on click of radio button. I have written below jQuery code and called it on load for initial page state and every click of radio.

JQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    function refreshMe(){
        $("#loading").show();

        var dt = new Date();
        var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
        $("#refreshDiv").html(time);
        $("#loading").hide();
    }

    // call the method on radio click:
    $(document).on('click', '#myRadio', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        refreshMe();
    });

    // call the method when page is opened:
    refreshMe();

});
```

HTML :

```
<input type='radio' id='myRadio'>
<div id='refreshDiv'></div>
```

For example you can ride [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Narendrad/sk4bxmpr/2/)

Let me know if you face any query/concern regarding this.

Comment: In the case mentioned in OP, radio button is within the div that needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Please check [this](jsfiddle.net/sk4bxmpr/3/). 
html() function will replace whole content of div so you can use it as your requirement.

Have update code as per your requirement. Let me know if you face any further query/concern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function loadRegister(val, myAttrData){
 $("div.abc").text("Hello! My value is="+val+" and Data is="+myAttrData);

}
```

Similarly you can write your loadGraph() too. Let me know if it helps you.