# Refresh a Static Div With Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am curious if this is even possible...

From my search, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375793/is-it-possible-to-refresh-a-div-on-a-radio-button-click) question here on SO, but it seems to be a bit different from my predicament.

For those not caring to check the post, someone is trying to refresh a div just by pressing a radio button (that is placed within the same div being replaced). It seems from the answers, that it was successful.

**My Issue**

I am working on a project that is set up in this manner:

- Row of radio buttons indicating how many days of the week they want to select (3 or 5 days), or just 1 day.
- If the user selects `1 day`, there is an invisible div under the row that *does not* appear.
- If the user selects 3 or 5 days, an invisible div is then shown under the row with another row, containing the days of the week.
- If the user selects `3 days`, they are only able to click on 3 of the days, and the other 4 are then disabled (*these "day" buttons are checkboxes*)
- If the user selects `5 days`, you guessed it, they can then select 5 days.
- If the user then **reselects** `3 days`, then they must unselect all of the days, and reselect them in order for the 3 day limit to be enforced, considering they've selected days already with `5 days` being selected.
- When a checkbox is selected, a CSS style is activated on it and then the color of it changes.

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to make my layout work in **this** manner:

- If a user selects `5 days`, do business as usual.
- If the user *then* selects `3 days`, I want the invisible div (now visible because `one day` was not the option selected) to refresh itself: By this, I mean have the CSS style removed and all checkboxes, unchecked.

**My Code**

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $('input[name=timing]').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).prop('id') == "one") {
      $('#recurrence_time').html('One Time');
      $('.day-selections').hide();
    } else if ($(this).prop('id') == "thrice") {
      $('#recurrence_time').html('3 Times a Week');
      $('.day-selections').show();
    } else if ($(this).prop('id') == "once") {
      $('#recurrence_time').html('Once a Week');
      $('.day-selections').hide();
    } else if ($(this).prop('id') == "custom") {
      $('#recurrence_time').html('Custom');
      $('.day-selections').show();
    }
  });
});

$(":checkbox[name=day]").change(function() {
  if ($('input#thrice').is(':checked')) {
    var len = 3;
  } else if ($('input#custom').is(':checked')) {
    var len = 5;
  }
  if ($(":checkbox[name=day]:checked").length == len) {
    $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});

function updateHighlightRadio() {
  var selected = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("selected")[0];
  if (selected) selected.className = selected.className.replace(" selected", "");
  this.parentNode.className += " selected";
}

window.onload = function() {
  var radios = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; ++i) {
    radios[i].onchange = updateHighlightRadio;
  }
}

$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
  $(this).closest("label").toggleClass(" selected");
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: #FF8C00;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.how-often p {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}


/* button label */

.recurrence {
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd199;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 115px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}


/* remove radio button */

.recurrence input {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}


/* color change when hovering */

.recurrence:hover {
  background-color: #FF8C00;
}

.days {
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd199;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 75px;
}


/* remove radio button */

.days input {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}


/* color change when hovering */

.days:hover {
  background-color: #FF8C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="how-often pricing">
  <p>How often?</p>
  <label class="recurrence">
                            <input required id="one" name="timing" type="radio">Once
                        </label>
  <label class="recurrence">
                            <input id="once" name="timing" type="radio">Once a week
                        </label>
  <label class="recurrence">
                            <input id="thrice" name="timing" type="radio">3 Times a week
                        </label>
  <label class="recurrence">
                            <input id="custom" name="timing" type="radio">Custom
                        </label>
  <hr>
</div>

<!--start day selection section-->
<div class="day-selections" style="display: none;">
  <p>Which days?</p>
  <label class="days">
                            <input id="mon" name="day" type="checkbox">
                            Monday
                        </label>
  <label class="days">
                            <input id="tue" name="day" type="checkbox">
                            Tuesday
                        </label>
  <label class="days">
                            <input id="wed" name="day" type="checkbox">
                            Wednesday
                        </label>
  <label class="days">
                            <input id="thu" name="day" type="checkbox">
                            Thursday
                        </label>
  <label class="days">
                            <input id="fri" name="day" type="checkbox">
                            Friday
                        </label>
  <hr>
</div>
```

**Note**: I cannot get the buttons to stay the new color once they are selected in my snippet for some reason...

Comment: Could you post a working snippet ?

Comment: I for some reason kept getting errors when I was working on adding more code to the snippet... I will post a JSFiddle in the later hours of the morning so that the `hide` and `show` functions of my code work along with the CSS styling... @SergeK.

Comment: Why are you making this more complex and not just having seperate radio buttons for 3 and 5 days? In this manner if they have selected 5 days, and then again select 3 days, the 5 days checkboxes selected will be removed to the initial unchecked boxes.

Comment: You can use SO snippet too, as @GerardoBLANCO did by [edit]ing your post

Comment: I could not get that to work when I tried adding more code to it, I was getting an error. @Highdef , they are all separate radio buttons.. I am not following what you are saying by the checkboxes will be unselected. Care to elaborate? :)

Comment: Thank you tons @SergeK. , it seems the issue persists the same with toggling the color change... I feel this may be crucial in being able to determine if the style added can then be stripped after the second button is selected

Comment: I've made a working prototype, still making the changes for highlight and stuff.

Comment: @Highdef , how wonderful that is. Thank you tons! I will as well try to add this into my working code and see how it turns out

Comment: @M.Gilbert I didn't notice your snippet until now, I was working on it. I hope, it helps you either way.

Comment: @Highdef I will dump it into my code here on my end, and if it works out, I will accept it as the answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: No problem at all :)

Comment: @M.Gilbert Updated the answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. The changes you need to make:

- Add classes and ID as demonstrated and instead of using javascript, you can just make use of CSS :checked selector and change the styles when selected.
- Keep your labels and inputs seperate and not nested, this way you can use the `for` attribute in label to connect to the checkbox and hide the checkbox using CSS `display:none`.
- For unchecking the checkboxes when another radio button is selected just make sure to remove the attribute checked from all the checkboxes as shown in the code for each if-else conditions `$('input.day').removeAttr('checked');` , compare the limit value for each of your radio buttons and if it exceeds the limit use the code and return it to false so no further checkboxes can be selected.

  `if ($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
  this.checked = false;
  }`

```js
$("document").ready(function() {

  $(".day-selections").hide();
  var limit = 0;
  $(':radio').click(function() {
    if ($('.notone').is(':checked')) {
      $(".day-selections").show();
      if ($('#thrice').is(':checked')) {
        limit = 3;
        $('input.day').removeAttr('checked');
        $('input.day').on('change', function(evt) {
          if ($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
            this.checked = false;
          }
        });
      } else if ($('#custom').is(':checked')) {
        limit = 5;
        $('input.day').removeAttr('checked');
        $('input.day').on('change', function(evt) {
          if ($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
            this.checked = false;
          }
        });
      }
    } else {
      $('input.day').removeAttr('checked');
      $(".day-selections").hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: #FF8C00;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.how-often p {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}


/* button label */

.recurrence {
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd199;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 115px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}


/* remove radio button */

.recurrence input {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}


/* color change when hovering */

.recurrence:hover {
  background-color: #FF8C00;
}

.days {
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd199;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 75px;
}

.day:checked+.days {
  background-color: #FF8C00;
}

.option {
  display: none;
}

.option:checked+.recurrence {
  background-color: #FF8C00;
}


/* remove radio button */

.day {
  display: none;
}

.days-selection {
  display: flex;
}


/* color change when hovering */

.days:hover {
  background-color: #FF8C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="how-often pricing">
  <p>How often?</p>

  <input required id="one" class="option" name="timing" type="radio">
  <label class="recurrence" for="one">Once</label>

  <input id="once" name="timing" class="option" type="radio">
  <label class="recurrence" for="once">Once a week</label>

  <input id="thrice" class="notone option" name="timing" type="radio">
  <label class="recurrence" for="thrice">3 Times a week</label>

  <input id="custom" class="notone option" name="timing" type="radio">
  <label class="recurrence" for="custom">Custom</label>
  <hr>
</div>
<!--start day selection section-->
<div class="day-selections" style="display: none;">
  <input id="mon" class="day" name="day" type="checkbox">
  <label class="days" for="mon">Monday
 </label>
  <input id="tue" class="day" name="day" type="checkbox">
  <label class="days" for="tue">Tuesday
 </label>
  <input id="wed" class="day" name="day" type="checkbox">
  <label class="days" for="wed">Wednesday
 </label>
  <input id="thu" class="day" name="day" type="checkbox">
  <label class="days" for="thu">Thursday</label>
  <input id="fri" class="day" name="day" type="checkbox">
  <label class="days" for="fri">Friday
 </label>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, friend! The limit for this new edit is not working, but I am loving the removal of the styling once they are unchecked... Still working on implementing this into my current code! I will get back to you once it is done! :)

Comment: Oh wait, a glitch.

Comment: Son of a gun... This is perfect. Thank you so much for the help! You are much appreciated.

Comment: @M.Gilbert Fixed the problem, there was a glitch in the if condition.

Comment: Thanks again. I am excited to get this into my code and pushed out!

Comment: @M.Gilbert Added the description of the changes made, hope it helps. Cheers :)